# Remove carriage returns from CSV data value

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed, text-processing

I am importing data from a pipe-delimited CSV to MySQL using a LOAD DATA INFILE statement. I am terminating lines by using '\r\n'. My problem is that some of the data within each row has '\r\n' in it, causing the load to error. I have similar files that just use '\n' within data to indicate linebreaks, and that causes no issues.

Example GOOD CSV

```
School|City|State|Country\r
Harvard University|Cambridge|MA|USA\r
Princeton University|Princeton|New
Jersey
|USA\r
```

Example BAD CSV

```
School|City|State|Country\r
Harvard University|Cambridge|MA|USA\r
Princeton University|Princeton|New\r
Jersey\r
|USA\r
```

Is there a way to pre-process the CSV, using sed, awk, or perl, to clean up the extra carriage return in the column values?

Comment: Yes Ed, unfortunately. This is the format I am given and I don't have the ability to change it.

Comment: do the rows have a fixed number of fields?

Comment: @ChrisTurner yes there is a fixed number of fields

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I can identify which field typically has the multiline data.

Comment: Sorry Ed, I didn't realize you had edited my original question. Reverted back.

Comment: I'm confused how the good example differs from the bad one - neither of them are valid CSV files due to the multi-line fields not being in quotes

Comment: @ChrisTurner While I agree they may be non-standard, the first one has `|`-separated records ending in `\r\n` so it's trivially and consistently uniformly parsable without quotes, e.g. with `gawk -v RS='\r\n' -F'|' ...`, while that is not the case for the second one because what should be the record terminating string `\r\n` can also appear mid-record. I'd actually have to check the RFC to be sure that first example is non-standard because quotes should only be necessary if a field can contain the separator (`|`) or the record terminator (`\r\n`) and only the 2nd example has that situation.

Comment: @EdMorton the only difference is that in my actual data, the bad data is in the 12th column. How would your script change based on that?

Comment: @EdMorton updated the question. Sorry about that

Comment: OK, I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608101/1745001) to work for your new example.

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution in perl. It reads in a line and if there are less than 4 fields, it keeps reading in the next line and merging it until it does have 4 fields. Just change the value of `$number_of_fields` to the right number.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $number_of_fields=4;

while(<STDIN>)
    {
    s/[\r\n]//g;
    my @fields=split(/\|/);
    next if($#fields==-1);   

    while($#fields<$number_of_fields-1)
        {
        my $nextline=<STDIN> || last;
        $nextline =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
        my @tmpfields=split(/\|/,$nextline);
        next if($#tmpfields==-1);
        $fields[$#fields] .= "\n".$tmpfields[0];
        shift @tmpfields;
        push @fields,@tmpfields;
        }
    print join("|",@fields),"\r\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^|]+[|]){3}[^|]+\r\n' -v ORS= '{$0=RT; gsub(/\r/,""); sub(/\n$/,"\r\n")} 1' file | cat -v
School|City|State|Country^M
Harvard University|Cambridge|MA|USA^M
Princeton University|Princeton|New
Jersey
|USA^M
```

Note that it assumes the number of fields is 4 so if you have some other number of fields then change `3` to that number minus 1. The script COULD instead calculate the number of fields by reading the first line of your input if that first line cannot have your problem:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { RS="\r\n"; ORS=""; FS="|" }
    FNR==1 { RS="([^|]+[|]){"NF-1"}[^|]+\r\n"; RT=$0 RT }
    { $0=RT; gsub(/\r/,""); sub(/\n$/,"\r\n"); print }
' file | cat -v
School|City|State|Country^M
Harvard University|Cambridge|MA|USA^M
Princeton University|Princeton|New
Jersey
|USA^M
```